# Filling missing values in a data.frame from another data.frame

Tags: r

I have a N x M data frame DF1 with row and column names, where many of values are NA. There is a second data frame DF2 (1 x M, so really could be a vector) with row names identical to DF1. I would like to use DF2 to fill up missing values in DF1 columns.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Udp: Sorry, really should have attached an example

Dataframe with NAs

```
> df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(9), nrow=3))
> df[1,1] <- NA
> df[2,2] <- NA
> df[3,3] <- NA
          X1         X2         X3
1         NA -0.1364313         NA
2 -0.7473972         NA -0.1662138
```

Substitution values (same row names, column names -- irrelevant

```
df2 = data.frame(c(1,2))
  c.1..2.
1       1
2       2
```

Expected output:

```
          X1         X2         X3
1         1  -0.1364313          1
2 -0.7473972          2 -0.1662138
```

Comment: How can DF2 fill up DF1 if it is M x 1? DF1 will have n times as many cells as DF1

Comment: You need to give an example of your problem, including sample data and your expected output

Comment: please provide reproducible code with sample data

Comment: @Symbolix Done. Thanks for the feedback. Hope now it makes more sense!

Comment: why does `df[1,3] = NA`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it, I think. First, I create a new `data.frame` (`new_df`), with only matching rows selected, then I perform an `sapply` over the data to replace `NA` values.

```
set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(9), nrow=3))
 df[1,1] <- NA
 df[2,2] <- NA
 df[3,3] <- NA
 df2 <- data.frame(c(1,2))
#create new data.frame
new_df <- df[which(row.names(df2) == row.names(df)),]
#use sapply() 
t(sapply(row.names(df2), FUN = function(x) 
     ifelse(is.na(new_df[row.names(new_df) == x,]), 
            df2[row.names(df2)== x,], 
            new_df[row.names(new_df) == x,])))

  [,1]       [,2]       [,3]     
1 1          0.07050839 0.4609162
2 -0.2301775 2          -1.265061
```

Note that this results in a loss of the column names...which probably means there's a better way of doing it. Also, my data is different since we did not use `set.seed`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do a simple for loop that will take care of this:

```
for(i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
    df[i,is.na(df[i,])] <- df2[i,]
}
```