# Convert values in one dataframe to NA based on NA's in a second dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm sure there is a very easy way to accomplish this task, but I cannot seem to figure it out. I have two data frames which have the exact same data but from two separate locations.

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,NA),b=c(1,5,4,6))
df2 <- data.frame(a=c(3,4,5,6),b=c(7,8,9,NA))
```

My desired output is two have a new version of df1 and df2 which are the exact same but the bottom row only contains NA values. I.e. if there is an NA value in one data frame, I need that replicated on the corresponding cell in the other data frame...

```
df1[4,2] <- NA
df2[4,1] <- NA
```

I have seen very similar questions addressing the problem from the opposite perspective (e.g. [Filling missing values in a data.frame from another data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015659/filling-missing-values-in-a-data-frame-from-another-data-frame)) but I can't figure how to apply this to my own data. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create an index based on the occurrence of `NA` in either of the two datasets and multiply

```
i1 <- NA^(is.na(df1)| is.na(df2))
df1 <- df1 * i1
df2 <- df2 * i1
```

Comment: Perfect thank you for this. I'll tick as soon as it allows me.

Comment: Interesting. So `NA^FALSE` == 1 and `NA^TRUE` == NA. Do you know why this is the case?

Comment: @EricWatt  The binary representation i.e `NA^1` is NA while `NA^0` is 1

Comment: Makes sense seeing it as `^1` and `^0`, I was distracted by the TRUE and FALSE instead. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some possibilities. (1) seems the cleanest and clearest in intent.  (3) works but seems unnecessarily complex in terms of sorting out side effects.

**1) replace** Try `replace`.

```
df1new <- replace(df1, is.na(df2), NA)
df2new <- replace(df2, is.na(df1), NA)
```

This would continue to work if `df1new` and `df2new` were replaced with `df1` and `df2` although it adds complexity.  In that case it might be better to assign `df1` and `df2` (i.e. `df1 <- df1new; df2 <-df2new`) afterwards to avoid complexity.

**2) indexing** It could alternately be written like this:

```
df1new <- df1
df1new[is.na(df2)] <- NA

df2new <- df2
df2new[is.na(df1)] <- NA
```

**3) destructive indexing** Not sure that this one is a good idea but it works here:

```
df1[is.na(df2)] <- df2[is.na(df1)] <- NA
```